# Google and Yahoo Weather API

Tags: weather

I created a google weather api which allowed a user to type in a city and get weather details back for 3 days.

Google have since shut this service down.

With yahoo api i need a WOEID to get the weatehr details. Is there a way for me to get weather from yahoo for 3 days and change a location to a WOEID in the process or should i look at alternative api. An example of what yahoo api requires is below.

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=SFXX0044&u=c&d=5

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using [forecast.io](https://developer.forecast.io/), which is very easy to use APIs with rich weather data sources

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this free weather API - https://www.mashape.com/george-vustrey/ultimate-weather-forecasts#!documentation

Sample result of San Francisco 7-day weather:

```
[
 {
  "day_of_week": "Mon",
  "high": "80.23",
  "low": "56.19",
  "condition": "Partly cloudy in the evening."
 },
 {
  "day_of_week": "Tue",
  "high": "78.32",
  "low": "59.2",
  "condition": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day."
 },
 {
  "day_of_week": "Wed",
  "high": "87.21",
  "low": "57.64",
  "condition": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day."
 },
 {
  "day_of_week": "Thu",
  "high": "90.1",
  "low": "60.91",
  "condition": "Clear throughout the day."
 },
 {
  "day_of_week": "Fri",
  "high": "88.66",
  "low": "57.88",
  "condition": "Clear throughout the day."
 },
 {
  "day_of_week": "Sat",
  "high": "86.5",
  "low": "54.11",
  "condition": "Partly cloudy in the morning."
 },
{
  "day_of_week": "Sun",
  "high": "89.62",
  "low": "52.42",
  "condition": "Clear throughout the day."
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [OpenWeatherMap](http://www.openweathermap.org/) for my website. One alternative you may check out.

Answer (score 1):

Another good alternative would be the [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/). for any given location it offers the urrent conditions, the weather forcast and a very attractive interactive map.

The OpenWeatherMap offers historical data, although the list of available cities of the free weather data plan is limited. Unlike the Weather Underground API it allows for a lot more than 500 calls per day.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at an alternative. Getting the WOEID is complex (and changing to a pay-per search model), and Yahoo's API doesn't offer much more than the current conditions at the location.

The [Weather Underground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history) is one that offers a fairly rich amount of history. However, if you exceed 500 calls/day, it will cost you at least $520 per month for their API access.

There are other weather APIs out there. Most history APIs are paid services. It pays to shop around for the best price for what you need.

If you're site is country-specific, your country may have a free data product.  Look at the NOAA data services for the USA or the Met Office services in the UK for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Yahoo! weather APIs](http://soup.metwit.com/post/47181933854/an-alternative-to-yahoo-weather-api) is DEAD at 3rd April, 2013.

You can use Metwit [weather api](http://metwit.com/weather-api/).
If you can implement them client-side: 200 request/day (ip based throttling) no authentication required. Worldwide coverage, JSON and REST compliant. You can register for extra API calls for free and if you still need it to call them server side the basic plan is pretty cheap.

Here a little example in jQuery: http://jsbin.com/isukam/1 that use our [weather resource](http://metwit.com/weather-api/docs/resources/weather/).

Full disclosure: I own this sweet piece of API.

Comment: I'm using Yahoo API and it still works.